# Kubernetes no compatible version found (dotnet)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, server, google-kubernetes-engine

**My Error in Logs Explorer when I deploy my App in Google Cloud>Workloads**

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.

The following frameworks were found:
5.0.4 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:

https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

COPY /out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

This is the code which is supposed to run

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpListener tcpListener;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 26950);
   
            tcpListener.Start();
         
            tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);
            Console.ReadKey();
           
        }
        private static void TCPConnectCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
        {
            TcpClient _client = tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(_result);
            tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Comment: Try `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1`

Comment: I tried it and got the following error:                                                                                      It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 145
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 145
Thank you for your suggestion, though.

Comment: Looking at it again, you should add that line just before the line `COPY /out .` keeping everything else same, ie use two different images, sdk one for building and runtime one for well, running.

Comment: @MatJ hm, it didn't work. I got the same error I describe in my question except it said that it didnt find any framwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using latest image of `sdk` which in this case is version `5.0.4`. You need to use it `3.1.0` as your application:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
```

Try one of these Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1 .
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:80"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

or

````
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]```
````

Comment: This way I get the same error except "The following frameworks were found: 5.0.4 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]" becomes "- No frameworks were found."

Comment: What framework of .Net Core are you targeting on your application?

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
     
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
This is my .csproj file so I guess I am targeting netcoreapp3.1

Comment: @apprentice just updated the answer. Check it and give it a try :)

Comment: I got the same error again :/ I assume you got the code from the tutorial. If so, the issue about it might be that in the tutorial they actually use a WebBuilder etc. but my App only is a host for a TCP connection without a frontend